# QField: Add and fill ring tool

Tags: qgis, editing, digitizing, vector-layer, qfield

When editing a polygon in QField, the polygon is highlighted in red. This makes it almost opaque and difficult to use the fill ring tool if digitising over a feature shown on the base map below. Is there a solution to this problem? I've tried playing with the rubberband settings in QGIS but this doesn't seem to make a difference in QField.

Comment: If you could share an image, it would be helpful to see what the problem is

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fe8zxxlufbv941l/Screenshot_20201226-184837_QField.jpg?dl=0

The polygon in edit mode is highlighted in red. This makes it difficult to see the underlying basemap and create rings/fill rings based on the basemap