# QField not implementing digitizing rubberband fill color option (including Don't update rubber band during node editing) set in QGIS 3.28

Tags: qfield, digitizing

I am digitizing features on a map using a project generated in QGIS 3.28 or even QGIS 2.18. Under QGIS the project follows the settings that adjust the fill color of the rubber band (including Don't update rubber band during node editing) that shows up when digitizing. However, when the project is transferred to QField v 2.6.3 and subsequently doing digitizing a heavy red fill occupies the interior of the rubberband covering up the underlying details. With the covered base map there's no visual guide in a number of situations where vertices are to be placed. A similar thread is found in [QField: Add and fill ring tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382950/qfield-add-and-fill-ring-tool) but it did not get any response.

[image]
[image]